# asp element nested in a bootstrap navbar issue:

Tags: asp.net, bootstrap-4

I am trying to nest an asp element into a bootstrap navbar...this is what I am getting with this code.  Nothing works to align it right..all the way right.

[image]

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
                     <ul class="navbar-nav">
                          <li class="nav-item">
                                 <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact US</a>
                          </li>
                          <li class="nav-item">
                                 <a class="nav-link" href="#">Support</a>
                          </li>
                          <li class="nav-item">
                                 <a class="nav-link" href="#">Help</a>
                         </li>
                     </ul> 
                     <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-right align-items-end">
                         <li>
                                 <asp:Label ID="WelcomeLabel" runat="server" CssClass="white"></asp:Label>
                                 <asp:Image ID="Flag_image" runat="server" CssClass="flag" Width="40px" Height="30px"/>
                        </li>
                     </ul>
               </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
                     <ul class="navbar-nav">
                          <li class="nav-item">
                                 <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact US</a>
                          </li>
                          <li class="nav-item">
                                 <a class="nav-link" href="#">Support</a>
                          </li>
                          <li class="nav-item">
                                 <a class="nav-link" href="#">Help</a>
                         </li>
                     </ul> 
                   </div>
<div>
                     <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-right align-items-end nav justify-content-end">
                         <li>
                                 <asp:Label ID="WelcomeLabel" runat="server" CssClass="white"></asp:Label>
                                 <asp:Image ID="Flag_image" runat="server" CssClass="flag" Width="40px" Height="30px"/>
                        </li>
                     </ul>
               </div>
```

Comment: This did not fix it.  The name and flag end up on the right of the button.collapsible

Answer (score 0):

It will work for you. [js fiddel](https://jsfiddle.net/pdx02ajn/1/)

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>

      </ul>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
      <li ><a href="#">Right</a></li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </nav>
```

Comment: I just attach a fiddle please try it. @JasonPietka

Answer (score 0):

This actually fixed it perfectly.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapsibleNavbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav" id="width">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Support</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item" id="heightnav">
            <asp:LinkButton ID="logOutBTN" runat="server" OnClick="logOutBTN_Click">Sign Out</asp:LinkButton>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <table class="height" align="right">
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style1"><asp:Image ID="Flag_image" runat="server" Width="40px" Height="30px" ImageAlign="Right"/></td>
            <td style="text-align: right"><asp:Label ID="WelcomeLabel" runat="server" CssClass="white"></asp:Label></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```